# Replace words on given line numbers

Tags: linux, awk, text-editing

I have a file `1.txt`

```
INTEGER-d_int ()
INTEGER-d_int  ()
INTEGER-d_int       (    )
INTEGER-d_intClass()
INTEGER-d_intClass     new()
```

and I want to replace the occurrence of `d_int` with `d_INT` on the lines 1 and 5.

In my case these line numbers are in a variable.

Comment: Since you tagged this with awk, is this the only possibility? What have you already tried?

Comment: I not sure whether it will work in awk . I want result can use any command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set variables a and b to the lines that you want to do the substitution on and then run awk:

```
a=1; b=5; awk '{ if (NR=='"$a"' || NR=='"$b"') sub("d_int","d_INT",$0); print $0}' 1.txt
```

In the above, awk checks to see if we are on line number `$a` or on line number `$b`.  If so, it performs the substitution.

Part of the trick of using `awk` is to protect the `awk` commands from the shell.  To do this, the `awk` commands are in single quotes everywhere except where we explicitly want the shell to substitute in for `$a` and `$b`.  `$a` and `$b` are each in double-quotes.

On your sample `1.txt`, the above produces:

```
INTEGER-d_INT ()
INTEGER-d_int  ()
INTEGER-d_int       (    )
INTEGER-d_intClass()
INTEGER-d_INTClass     new()
```

#### Alternative Approach

`sed` can also be used for this.  The sed command for changing only line 1 is `1 s/d_int/d_INT/` and the `sed` command for changing only line 5 is `5 s/d_int/d_INT/`.  Thus, using shell substitution, a `sed` program to do the substitutions on lines `a` and `b` is:

```
a=1; b=5; s='s/d_int/d_INT/' ; sed "$a $s; $b $s" 1.txt
```

#### Extension to an arbitrary number of lines

Suppose that we are supplied with an arbitrary list of `lines` on which to apply the substitution:

```
lines="1 5 6 9 15 19 20"
s='s/d_int/d_INT/'
for line in $lines
do
    echo line=$line
    cmd="$line $s; $cmd"
done
echo cmd=$cmd
sed "$cmd" 1.txt
```

Comment: +1 also for the nice, clear explanation

Comment: thanks.. I have a file or a variable which is having the line numbers and i want replace the words on that lines , is that possible?

Comment: @Timson Probably.  Let me know what your "file or variable" looks like.

Comment: echo $lines - 1 5 6 9 15 19 20

Comment: @Timson See updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
sed -i '1,5s/d_int/d_INT/' 1.txt
```

Comment: Nope, this does not work. Also, you should probably explain one-liners a bit.

Comment: It changes lines one through five

Comment: Says -i:edit the file 1,5s:subst. in lines between 1 and 5, maybe I didn't understand what you wanted exactly..